# Can we use "Person's name, When he verb to ..."

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, vocabulary, orthography

Can we say for example **"Oussama, when he wants to do something he does it"** rather than **"When Oussama wants to do something he does it"?**

What is the correct sentence grammatically, because someone said that the first sentence is bad expression to use because we mentioned the person's name alone without any verb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly permissible to put the subject's name at the beginning of the sentence in order to emphasise it. However, you don't need to include *he*, just another comma. The sentence is "Oussama does it" - the phrase "when he wants to do something," specifies *when* he does it.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that you can use this sentence, but it must be punctuated quite specifically, such as, 'Oussama: when he wants to do something, he does it.'
The colon gives the information you are expanding on about Oussama, and the comma is needed to delineate the subordinate and main clauses.

Comment: Did you intend a colon or semi-colon in your example?

Comment: Yes, sorry, a colon was meant. Therefore, the sentence begins with 'Oussama', and expands into the details about him, which works but has a slightly different meaning to the other example above.